# Batch: Getting folder info with subs into files

Tags: loops, batch-file, for-loop, nested

I have a folder structure like his. Headfolders with subfolders.

```
Folder1\subfolder1
Folder1\subfolder2
Folder2\subfolder1
etc.
```

I want to place a txt file in every subfolder with this in the textfile:

```
Foldername: Folder1
Subfoldername: subfolder2
```

The code below works, but only for one layer of folders, not with nested ones.

```
for /r "c:\test\subtest" %%f in (.) do (
copy "C:\info.txt" "%%~ff" > nul
echo Foldername: %%~nxf>>%%~ff\info.txt
```

How can I get also the nested info into the txt file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want two levels (folder and subfolder) I would do it simply like this:

```
@echo off
for /d %%a in (*) do (
    for /d %%b in ("%%~a\*") do (
        echo>"%%~b\info.txt" Foldername: %%~a
        echo>>"%%~b\info.txt" Subfoldername: %%~nxb
    )
)
```

If you want it in all subfolders for some variable depth it's probably easier to run a `FOR /F` loop on the output of `DIR /S /B /AD` along with some string substitution, perhaps.